# Number of Palindromic Substrings- error in dynamic programming

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve the number of palindromic substrings problem using DP.

The problem requires us to find the number of palindromic substrings in a string.

My current code is as follows:

```py
def palindromic_substrings(s):
    result = 0

    dp = [[False] * len(s) for i in range(len(s))]

    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(i, len(s)):
            dp[i][j] = j-i <= 1 or (s[i] == s[j] and dp[i+1][j-1])
            if dp[i][j]:
                result += 1
  
    return result

print(palindromic_substrings("aaa")) # returns 5- should be 6
```

My logic is a follows:

Let `dp[i][j]` represents whether the substring defined by `s[i:j]` is a palindromic substring. There are two cases to consider to determine `dp[i][j]`.

The first is noticing that any substring of length less than 2 is always a palindrome i.e. `j-i <= 1`.

The second is that any substring that has length greater than 2 is a palindrome iff the first and last characters are the same and the inner substring, excluding the first and last characters is a palindrome i.e. `s[i] == s[j] and dp[i+1][j-1]`.

If `dp[i][j]` is `True` i.e. it is palindromic, we increment the `result`.

My code is returning the wrong result and I'm unsure where the gap in my logic is.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you maybe start by explaining your logic to us?

Comment: For instance, what does the value in `dp[i][j]` represent? And how do you explain your recurrence formula and your base cases?

Comment: Also, instead of just examining the return value `result`, I encourage you to return the whole array `dp`, so you can see exactly which values are wrong. What are the six palindromic substrings of `"aaa"`, according to you? And what are the five palindromic substrings that were counted by your function? Presumably, your function missed at least one substring, and you can identify which one.

Comment: In other words, replace `return result` with `return (result, dp)`, then test by doing `s = "aaa"; result, dp = palindromic_substrings(s); print(result); print([s[i:j] for i in range(len(s)) for j in range(len(s)) if dp[i][j]])`

Comment: I have explained my logic. Hope it is clear enough.

Comment: Okay, I think I found your bug. The values in `dp` are updated in the wrong order. The recurrence formula for `dp[i][j]` relies on the value for `dp[i+1][j-1]`, therefore `dp[i+1][j-1]` must be computed **before** `dp[i][j]`. But since your loops are in increasing order of `i`, `dp[i][j]` is computed first, using the wrong value for `dp[i+1][j-1]`

Comment: I suggest looping on the substrings in order of length, something like: `for length in range(len(s)): for i in range(len(s) - length): j = i + length; ...`

Comment: But also I really, really strongly suggest to follow my advice above, and return the whole `dp` so you can examine it. Just looking at the result value `result` is not enough to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is inspired by @Stef great comments, so the working code will be like this:  (credit to him, question for me... ;-)

```py
def countSubstrings(self, s: str) -> int:
    n = len(s)
    dp = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]
        
    ans = 0
    for i in range(n-1, -1, -1):
        for j in range(i, n):
            dp[i][j] = s[i] == s[j] and ((j-i+1) < 3 or dp[i+1][j-1])
            ans += dp[i][j]
    return ans
```

#### And this is non-DP version to compare:

```py
 def countSubstrings(self, s: str) -> int:
     count = 0
     n = len(s)

     for i in range(2 * n - 1):

         left  =  i // 2
         right = (i+1) //  2
            
         while left >= 0 and right <n and s[left] == s[right]:
             count += 1
             left -= 1
             right += 1

     return count
```